# convert int number to separated number each 3 digits by comma

Tags: ios

I trying to convert int number to separated number by comma after each 3 digits by comma, I do know how to format that in NSString but it would not work if it is int/float.
my question is : how can I return float separated number by comma in this function

```
- (CGFloat)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return //for example 453,453,000.45;
}
```

Comment: I'd say that you just have to return in your example `453453000.45` (as a CGFloat), and use a `NSNumberFormatter` (I guess) in the method that should "show" the labels. My guess is that (datasource?) method want the value to compare, but that's not the one that will show/render it. EDIT: From the GitHub, you have: `- (NSString *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart textForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;` That's the one to use your specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `NSNumberFormatter`. Like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

//Set the required formatting style
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString *formattedNumberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10000000.0f]];
//output would be 10,000,000.0
```

Comment: *sidenote:* `NSNumberFormatter` is a quite memory-eating class. Try to reduce the instance you create

Comment: Yes I agree with you @raptor.. It anyone wants to format numbers frequently, then it is better to create it as class member, set formatting style and then just format the number using that instance.

Comment: thank you thats right, but if converted that to float for returning it will come back no commas !

Comment: a number either int or float does not contain commas. Commas are used for numbers to increase their understanding and readability. You can not get commas inserted int or float.. Not possible in any programming language.